# force files and/or directory into the kernel file cache

Tags: linux, cache, kernel

Is there any way of forcing or prioritizing a directory, files or files being written/read by a certain process into the kernel file cache?

edit: system is linux.

edit: I have 1 process which writes a file and about 7-10 processes which read the file thats written by the one process. I'd like to minimize the overall disk i/o involved.

Comment: Please describe the problem you're trying to solve, rather than asking us how to implement the poorly-conceived solution you've come up with.

Comment: I added a few more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kernel will take the optimal caching action automatically, assuming that you have sufficient memory to carry all of the cache.  Attempting to preseed the cache isn't going to be helpful in the general case; it is only of use when you need to have quick user-visible processing time, at the expense of more time involved earlier in the process, which doesn't appear to be the case here.

If you need the best possible I/O rate, and you don't care if you lose the file data in the event of a catastrophe, you can do the file I/O on a ramdisk (tmpfs); this will completely eradicate the disk I/O, but the contents of the filesystem will be lost on reboot.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the files should "force" them into the cache. I assume you want to preload some files into cache?

I am tempted to say that "dd if=file of=/dev/null bs=4M" should force the file into the cache.
Are you talking about Linux?

Comment: yes the system is linux